# Plotting 2 data sets with a scatter matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I can already plot the data from one data frame using `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix`, but can you plot 2 data sets that have the same units in the same scatter matrix? changing colors between them to differentiate which data belongs to which data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a reference to an Axes object to keep drawing on the same subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(100)
y = range(100,200)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')
ax1.scatter(x[40:],y[40:], s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()][1]][1]
```

[image: Plot]

Another option is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x,y, c='b', marker='x', label='1')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', marker='s', label='-1')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```